How to fix UTF-8 with cyrillic problem in my code?
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF-8");
    locale global(locale(".UTF-8"));

    const float Pi = 3.14;

    float r, h;
    
    cout << "Введіть довжину (r): ";
    cin >> r;

    cout << "Введіть висоту (h): ";
    cin >> h;


    float d, s, v, sb;

    d = 2 * r;
    sb = 2 * Pi * r * h;
    s = 2 * Pi * r*(r + h);
    v = Pi * pow(r, 2) * h; 

    cout << "d = " << d << "\nSбіч = " << sb << "\nS= "<< s <<"\nV= " << v;

    return 0;

}

(English Win11)
I tried:
setlocale (LC_ALL, "ukr";
and
setlocale (LC_ALL, ".UTF-8");
locale global(locale(".UTF-8"));
and
Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage checkbox
and also
edit my region settings.
But nothing of this wont work

possible duplicate of Properly print utf8 characters in windows console

It's easier to use UTF-16 in Windows than UTF-8. And there is no UTF-8 in your code unless you are saving the source file in that encoding. You can't save a file in 'Unicode', because Unicode is a character set, not an encoding.

SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);?

This works for me
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"Введіть довжину (r):\n";
    return 0;
}

It's the simple way to print Unicode characters on Windows. Put the stream into _O_U16TEXT mode and use wide strings L"..." and wide streams std::wcout.

what does the 3rd library do? I removed it and the code still works.

@thearsw • by "3rd library", do you mean the Windows operating system library?

@thearsw -- windows specific headers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170

there is no need to _setmode to UFT16, i.e. simple 2byte, when using std::wcout -- it's automatic

Actually this shouldn't work, because wide-string (adding zeros) doesn't represent Cyrillic  characters, which have 0400–04FF range (see https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf). Here is a test: https://godbolt.org/z/7jdcvaPY7
